# NextJS CSR Build Error with jQuery - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')

Tags: jquery, next.js

I am developing a React application with client-side rendering (CSR), and I am using jQuery along with Evo Calendar for a custom calendar component. The application works fine, but during the build process, I encounter the following error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')
at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Kamran\Documents\GitHub\bvdudet-acm-website-v2\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
at eval (./src/app/events/page.js:9:64)
```

Code Snippet:

```js
"use client";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import "./custom-calendar.scss";
import "evo-calendar/evo-calendar/js/evo-calendar.js";

const Page = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof document !== "undefined") {
      $("#calendar").evoCalendar({
        language: "en",
        todayHighlight: true,
        calendarEvents: [
          {
            id: "1", // Event's ID (required)
            badge: "", // Event badge (optional)
            name: "", // Event name (required)
            description: "", // Event description (optional)
            date: ["September/20/2023"], // Event date (required)
            type: "event", // Event type (required)
            everyYear: false, // Same event every year (optional)
            color: "#63d867", // Event custom color (optional)
          },
        ],
      });
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <span>
          lorem
        </span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div
          id="calendar"
          style={{
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Solving  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')`